# lpr command - how to force black and white?

Tags: command-line, cups, lpr

I have troubles with the LPR command. Before the printer has changed. I ran my instructions using

`lpr -P printer_name -o raw file_name`

Now I need to run print instructions on the new printer which only accepts black and white printed colors.
After browsing the internet, I found the option saturation=0 but without success.

example : `lpr -P printer_name -o saturation=0 -o raw file_name`

I have also tried to edit the *DefaultColorModel: CMYK parameter of the ppd file and change it ofr *DefaultColorModel: Gray but it doesn't work either.

By using meld, I compared the .ppd file and printer.conf after printing with my ubuntu and ctrl+P but I don't see anything useful.

Can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found the right option.

If you need lock black and white for printing. You need use ColorModel option like this :

```
lpr -P printer_name -o ColorModel=KGray file_name
```